# How do I display a jpeg attachment as an image rather than as a link on an InfoPath form?

Tags: document-library, infopath, attachments, jpg

After reading this article: [InfoPath 2007 - Extracting Those Pesky Binary Attachments](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-8-InfoPath_2007_-_Extracting_those_pesky_Binary_attachments.aspx), I notice that Visual Studio is required in order to display the attachment file rather than as a link to the attachment file.

However, in my case, I have the form where end-users only upload attachments: a JPG file. The question is; what should I do to make the JPG file display on the InfoPath form itself.

Currently, the form displays a link to the attachment JPG file rather than letting end-user to view the JPG file together with the rest of the contents inside the InfoPath form.

I'm open to any solution that will allow me to view both the InfoPath form content & the JPG image on a single page without the need to use Visual Studio.

Extra info: The InfoPath form is located in one of our SharePoint 2007 Libraries.